# How can I access X server at boot?

Tags: x11, xorg, x-server

I am running a Java Swing application on Linux. I wrapped the Java code with a service.

I can start my_java_service from command prompt without any issue.

I want my application to start at start-up. So I copied my_java_service to /etc/rc5.d folder using `update-rc.d` command.

Start order of the X server is START20 (S20).

So I gave the start order of START55 (S55) to my_java_service.

The error I get is this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
```

I believe my_java_service can not reach the X server at start-up.

I used `xhost +local:all` in my_java_service but it did nothing.

How can I reach X server and start my app at start-up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would get this working, your application's windows would pop up on the login screen, accessible to anyone who walks past - do you really want this?

And when someone logs in, I think any windows started on the login screen will be forced to terminate, so your application would have to detect the user login and somehow re-establish the connection to that user's session. When someone logs out using the GUI, a X server reset will be triggered that will definitely force all X applications to disconnect from the server. That would require a complex re-connection logic, or accepting that the local GUI must not be used while your service is running.

If your actual requirement is just to run the java service independent of user logins/logouts on the GUI console, a better solution would be to set up a separate X server for your application.

If you need to sometimes interact with the application, a stand-alone VNC X server would probably be suitable. It would have its own virtual display you could connect to using a VNC client if necessary.

If there is no need to interact with the application using the local GUI at all, then you could run the application using a *virtual framebuffer X server*, which has no real display at all, but otherwise behaves just like a real X server. You might find it packaged by your Linux distribution as `xvfb` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for the help and the info, stand-alone VNC X server is the most appropriate in my case.